# AngularJS currency filter - remove extra zeros from fraction

Tags: angularjs

In core `maxFrac` is set to `8`.

So if the `amount` is 10.22, after applying `currency filter` amount is changed to `10.22000000`.

My issue is that I want to remove the tailing zeros.

My expected results are as follows,

```
amount = 10, result = 10
amount = 10.32 result = 10.32
amount = 10.2233445566, result = 10.22334455
```

Is there any settings for doing this??

Please help me to find a solution...

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use the filter [number](http://number):

```
<span>{{amount | number:2}}</span>
```

If you are already applying some other filter to `amount`, then apply `number` afterwards:

```
<span>{{amount | someFilter | number:2}}</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using it as a HTML template binding you can set the fraction size in itself:

```
{{ variable | currency:2 }}
```

In Javascript:

```
$filter('currency')(variable, 2);
```